# How can you show and hide the cookies icon in the Chrome address bar?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, cookies

In the picture of a Chrome address bar below, the cookies icon is missing. How is that possible/accomplished?

[image: Pic without cookies icon]

In this pick below, the address bar contains the cookie icon (which sometimes can have a red x to saw that cookies are disabled.

[image: Pic with icon]

I am trying to actually figure out a login problem in Chrome for our website.  At certain random times, it appears that cookies don't get set. Other browsers are able to login. The problem then somehow corrects itself.

Trying to gather as much info on cookies in Chrom so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Icons appear in the address bar only to alert you about blocked or set cookies:

- The blocked cookies icon appears whenever a cookie has been blocked on the page you’re viewing, even if you’ve allowed all local data by default, due to exceptions you’ve made for specific domains.
- The allowed cookies icon appears whenever cookies have been set on the page you’re viewing, even though you’ve blocked all cookies by default, due to exceptions you’ve made for specific domains.

That means that when these conditions are not fulfilled, no icon will be displayed. See [Manage your cookies and site data](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95647?hl=en) for more details.